# Jump to opening tag in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

When i'm debugging html files on VS Code, how can i simply jump to the opening tag of a  tag ?

Let's say i'm on the  tag (line 2938) of the example below ; i just want to jump for its opening  tab, but it's a large file and i can't find it. Is there a shortcut for that ?

When the cursor is on this  tag, it will highlight the opening , but as it's hundred of lines above, i need to scroll and manually search for it, i'm sure that is a better way !

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

run the `Emmet: go to matching pair` command.

place the cursor on the closing tag.  Press F1. type `matching pair` or any portion of the matching pair command. Then press enter.

Answer (score 6):

1. **Click on** your desired (opening or closing) tag in your file.
   [image]
2. **Hit `ctr-shift-P`** (on Windows), or `cmd-shift-P` (on Mac)
   to get the **Emmet prompt**.
   (Emmet is an editor plugin that is built right into Visual Studio Code. No extensions/plugins are needed.)
3. **Type in 'match'**.
4. **Click on** [Emmet: go to matching pair]

You will be taken to the matching pair.

[image]

You can also add a **shortcut key** to avoid having to do all of the above:

1. **Go to** `File > Preferences > Keyboard Shortcuts`
2. **Type in** 'emmet mat'
3. **Click on** +, and type in your desired combo.
   [image]